# Magento 2 extend styles-m.less

Tags: magento2, layout, less, rwd

I'm working on a custom Magento 2 theme and I added couple of my own elements in it. When I write (for example):

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {
  .example_element{width:100px;}
}
.example_element{widht:200px;}
```

The code from media query is always overwritten by code below. I'm writing this code in my _theme.less file and it ends up in style-m.css. Yes I can use !important - but that is not the idea. I would like to know where do I need to write my responsive css / less code in order to work properly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {
      .example_element{width:100px;}
}
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .example_element{widht:200px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This goes in style-m.css, that generates the common and mobile styles

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
   .example_element{
       width:100px;
   }
}
```

This goes in style-l.css, that generates the desktop styles (Up to 768px)

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
          .example_element{
               width:200px;
           }
    }
```

The mobile first approach is better so mobile devices don't even load the desktop styles.

[Here the doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_css.html)